# Google Maps HeatmapLayer clickable endpoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, heatmap

When a user reaches a zoom level where the cluster only consist of 1-4 LatLng points I would like to make the object clickable to show source of the data used for the heatmap.
Any tips on how to address this issue?
Can I connect any type of EventListener to the HeatmapLayer points?

Comment: where do the data come from?

Comment: The data is from Instagram. You can see my heatmap on this site [link](http://www.geoklubb.se/instagram/). See how I build the data through the instagramData array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no click-event for a heatmap(  basically there isn't any event a heatmap will listen to).

What you can do: use a markerClusterer.

Create Markers for all points, as markerImage assign a a transparent image(a size of 15x15 should be fine) and apply the desired click-event to the marker.

Push the markers into a [markerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) and apply the following style to the clusterer:

```
  {
    url: 'path/to/transparentImage.png',
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    textColor: 'transparent',
    textSize: 0
  }
```

**Result:**

as long as the markers are clustered, you'll not see anything.

When a marker isn't clustered anymore, you'll also not see anything(because the marker is transparent), but you can click on the transparent marker, and the marker will respond to the click.